# Why is onClick being called on render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Bookmark extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.props.idt);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='bookmark' onClick={this.handleClick()}/>
    );
  }
}
export default Bookmark;
```

This is my code. I've binded the function but it is still called on render. This is also how they do it in the React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

It only works if I do it this way:

```
<div className='bookmark' onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>
```

Then handleClick is called only when I click the button.

Comment: This will work as well.`<div className='bookmark' onClick={this.handleClick}/>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are passing a method call instead of the method itself.

Change it to

```
<div className='bookmark' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didnt even notice the **()**.

Comment: I am new to JS, so my question is: Why does the method call still get called? The onClick has not been triggered so the method call should not be called, correct?